# Add new calendar appointments to clients Outlook from webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I have a website (ASP.net MVC2) where a database stores data/times of events. I want a client to be able to log in and sync these items to their Outlook. Is this at all possible? I've had a look around but haven't found anything useful, other than this isn't possible in javascript as that would open up all sorts of security holes snooping through users' registrys... If not, I may have to look into basic alternatives such as downloading xml documents with the event details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do it with [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx), but that is only for an Intranet application.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. My project is also only for use on an intranet which I didn't mention. I just read about using ActiveX in IE which seems very straightforward like the following...

outlook = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
appointment= outlook.CreateItem(1);
appointment.Subject = "Subject"; etc

... but seems a bit frowned upon as you have to enable activex, but this could be ok as it'll only be used on an intranet.